# Understanding results of nslookup

Tags: networking, server, command-line

I'm looking at the `nslookup` command, and I couldn't exactly understand the results it shows.

A sample output

```
nslookup ubuntu.com

Server:
192.168.0.1
Address: 192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.94.156
```

I have two questions:

1) What does the hash (`Address: 192.168.0.1#53`) of the address mean ?

2) What does the non-authoritative answer mean and why the address is different from the server part ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hash, and number after is the default TCP/UDP name server port.

Any answer that originates from the DNS Server which has the complete zone file information available for the domain is said to be `Authoritative answer`.

When the DNS servers maintains a cache file for the results of all queries performed in the past, and received an authoritative response, when a DNS query is asked for, it searches the cache file, and return the information available as `Non-Authoritative Answer`.